# R - how to sort named list of character vectors

Tags: r

I'm new to R and looking for the following:
My input:

```
v = list(bob=c("aa", "cc"), cas=c("tt", "ff"), john=c("aa", "bb")) 

v

$bob

[1] "aa" "cc"

$cas

[1] "tt" "ff"

$john

[1] "aa" "bb"
```

I want to sort based on the character vectors inside it, the desired output I'm looking for :

```
sorted_v

$john

[1] "aa" "bb"

$bob

[1] "aa" "cc"

$cas

[1] "tt" "ff"
```

How to obtain sorted_v?

Comment: Something like `v[order(vapply(v, toString, character(1L)))]` maybe? Not sure about all of your requirements for sorting....

Answer (score 3):

We can `paste` all the elements of the list together, `sort` them and extract the `names` of them.

```
sorted_v <- v[names(sort(sapply(v, paste0, collapse = "")))]
sorted_v

#$john
#[1] "aa" "bb"

#$bob
#[1] "aa" "cc"

#$cas
#[1] "tt" "ff"
```

OR

as @ycw mentioned in the comments we can also use `toString` instead of `paste0`, `collapse` combination :

```
sorted_v <- v[names(sort(sapply(v, toString)))]
```

Also using @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 and @ycw's inputs we can reduce it to

```
v[order(sapply(v, toString))]

#$john
#[1] "aa" "bb"

#$bob
#[1] "aa" "cc"

#$cas
#[1] "tt" "ff"
```

Comment: `sorted_v <- v[names(sort(sapply(v, toString)))]` This will also work.